# How to use NTEventLogAppender?

Tags: c++

I used this code in WindowXP, but I can't use NTEventLogAppender. I can't find the help document on NTEventLogAppender. Please give an example! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from my .properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, NTEvent

log4j.appender.NTEvent=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
log4j.appender.NTEvent.log=CompanyName
log4j.appender.NTEvent.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.NTEvent.source=ApplicationName
log4j.appender.NTEvent.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c][%l][%p][%thread]: %m%n
```

Don't forget to put NTEventLogAppender.dll in a directory mentioned in your Windows path or where your binaries are.